# What are the latest developments about global stilling?

Tags: climate, wind

I recently learn about "global stilling", i.e. the fact that surface wind speed tends to decrease since the 80s. It was in [this article](https://doi.org/10.1038/ngeo979), but it's from 2010. The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_terrestrial_stilling) also seems a bit outdated, as it mentions the STILLING project as "current" (it ended in 2018). Said project has only [one publication](https://cordis.europa.eu/project/id/703733/results), although interesting (it suggests that part of the trend is an artefact from anemometers not ageing well!). So I was wondering what were the latest developments in this field? Do we now have a better idea of what could cause this phenomenon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a thing of the past. Apparently around 2010 the 30 years calming trend reversed. Since then, wind speeds and wave heights are picking up quickly, possibly in a decadal variation pattern.

[Young et. al. 2010 Global Trends in Wind Speed and Wave Height](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/332/6028/451)

Possible application for the planning of wind turbines:

[Zhenzhong Zeng et.al. 2019 A reversal in global terrestrial stilling and its implications for wind energy production](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41558-019-0622-6)

From the abstract of the latter:

> ... we use wind data from in situ stations worldwide to show that the stilling reversed around 2010 and that global wind speeds over land have recovered. We illustrate that decadal-scale variations of near-surface wind are probably determined by internal decadal ocean–atmosphere oscillations, rather than by vegetation growth and/or urbanization as hypothesized previously. ...

Similar observations of an increasing trend over ocean surfaces, overlapping with the period of global stilling over land.

[Ching Wei Zheng et.al. 2016 Global oceanic wind speed trends](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0964569116300850)

Can only read the abstract of the latter. Would be interesting to investigate further the reason for the differing observation and modelling of sea- and land-wind speeds during the term.

Comment: Interesting, thanks, especially the second paper proposing another theory than increased roughness, which doesn't stand any more if the stilling is over.